# Dynamic time display on Java

Tags: java, time

I am trying to make a java application that display live time of different cities. But i need to make it display on console. My problem is i can make it with using loop but it prints newline when time is changing. I  am wondering if there is a way to make display live time without printing it to newline again and again. Thanks for help.

Comment: It would be cool to show what you have (code) what you get (output) and what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make it display on console

For a Window Command Prompt, I know that printing a `\r` at the end of a line, instead of `\n` or `\r\n`, will return the cursor to the beginning of the current line, so the next printed text will print over the previous text.

I don't know if this works on Linux.

I do know that it doesn't work in the Console output panes of some IDE's, e.g. `\r` behaves like `\n` in Eclipse.

Caveats aside, in a Windows Command Prompt, the following will display a running clock  on a single line:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
for (;;) { // loop forever
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
    System.out.print(time.format(formatter) + "\r");
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1_000_000_000 - time.getNano());
}
```

Note 1: The code uses `print()`, not `println()`, since the `ln` will print the `\r\n` we don't want.

Note 2: It prints *over* existing text, it doesn't clear the line, so if a line prints `Hello World\r` then `Goodbye\r`, the result is the text `Goodbyeorld`. You need to pad with spaces to clear any existing text. This is of course not a issue with *fixed-width* output like `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: Good answer. Details: While `for (;;)` is the C idiom for an infinite loop, the Java idiom goes `while (true)`, which more clearly expresses the intent. Rather than doing the time math I find `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(nanosToWait)` eleganter.

Comment: @OleV.V. Who says `while (true)` is the Java idiom for a forever loop? I prefer `for (;;)` since it reads almost like "forever". --- E.g. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/infinite-loops-java) shows 3 ways of writing an infinite loop, but shows no preference of one over another.

Answer (score 0):

Q: I'm wondering if there's a way to display ... without newline.

A: Yes.

The problem is that you appear to have a console-mode application, that uses System.out.println() (or equivalent). The solution is to use "something else".

- Ideally, you can use a GUI, like [Java Swing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/)
- Alternatively, if you still want a console-mode app, you can use a "curses" type library for Java.  For example: [Terminal and ncurses Java libraries](http://rememberjava.com/cli/2017/01/22/ncurses_terminal_libs.html)